# Why was "Getting a job in the games industry as a developer, just knowing a game engine" deleted?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

I logged in today to see -220 rep because [a question I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569326/getting-a-job-in-the-games-industry-as-a-developer-just-knowing-a-game-engine/2569688#2569688) a long time ago was deleted, is it possible to find out why?

```
"Getting a job in the games industry as a developer, just knowing a game engine"
```

I see a lot of other questions on this topic whose answers are specific to THAT question, so I understand the process and don't expect the question or rep to come back but i'd like to know why it was deleted or if it was migrated elsewhere? I'm mostly just curious about the reason it was deleted.

Comment: Now i'm more confused, my rep seems to have returned but the question remains deleted. How is this possible?

Comment: Reputation on your deleted post is preserved under the [new rules](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/); the post is more than 60 days old.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Career-development questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Those kinds of questions are also off-topic on the *Programmers* and *Game Development* SE sites as well.

Comment: So i assume it was closed as off topic a while ago and then deleted recently?

Comment: are those kind of questions relevant on "Programmers" or "Game Development" stack exchange sites? Could it have been migrated?

Comment: It was closed on Feb 1.  No, they're not on-topic there either.

Comment: @FraserGraham - old questions are almost never migrated like that, and, I must admit, for good reason.  Other SE sites exist for *new* questions, that need answers to help someone *today*.  They don't exist as a repository for old SO questions

Comment: Is there any SO site they are on-topic for?  Or is it just tough luck?

Comment: @smackfu: See http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/24003/career-advice