# Why was my question closed and down voted, but not this one

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, scope, broken-windows

Recently, I overreacted over a question ban thanks to this question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21531621/ada-vs-pascal-for-general-and-systems-programming

(Question Deleted), but I  was searching for a little while, and I found this.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195937/perl-compared-to-java

While it was closed once, it was reopened, and has not gotten any bad criticism. I was trying to communicate almost the exact same thing in my question, but it was closed, deleted, and down-voted. Why was this question not attacked like mine??

Comment: Thanks for pointing us at a 5 y/o question. Closed now.

Comment: Look at the date on that question. Then consider that the site changes over time ...

Comment: @Oded Apparently the question was reopened earlier.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1198019/2235132) seems to suggest so.

Comment: @devnull - Yep. Also in 2009.

Comment: @Oded I implied that _even in 2009_ it had been closed for whatever reason(s).

Comment: relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124635/how-many-questions-on-meta-have-asked-why-cant-i-ask-this-question-when-that

Answer (score 7):

Generally speaking, it's always better to look at *recent* questions and follow [the advice of the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), than it is to point at old questions as evidence that a new question is on-topic.

There will always be off-topic questions that still exist on the site.  This can happen for a number of reasons.  Some of these questions were more acceptable back then than they are now.  Some questions are so uninteresting that they never get enough views to achieve close velocity.