# Strawman argument made to keep closed post closed

Tags: discussion

I made a post which was flagged as off-topic in the CrossValidated site. I posted to the [meta](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2235/my-on-hold-question-needs-improvement) requesting review of this decision, because I believed the question to be on-topic by right of similarity with another post and by point in the On-Topic list for the site. And, I asked for advise how I could improve the post.

The moderator who originally flagged the post replied, pointing out the question should not be reopened because the flag was not for improvement, but off-topic.

In other words, no justification for the action was given. The fact of the original on-hold reason was given as the justification, ignoring my lead in to the post--where I pointed out what I said above.

That's not nice or fair. What gives? If the <del>forum</del> community is open to anyone, *"...regardless of skills and experience"* then such narrow interpretations of on-topic fail to meet this rule.

Comment: *"I fought the strawman and the strawman won."*  Can happen.  Good thing you won't end up wrongfully imprisoned ;)

Comment: Well, to be fair, it's kind of hard to tell someone how to improve a question which is just plain not on-topic for the site. That's kind of like asking Wal-Mart to price match another store on something they don't sell. Would you be upset if they told you "We don't sell that here"?

Comment: animuson. I made an appeal to the ruling it was off topic. The *better* response is to reply with the justification. Isn't that the responsibility of moderation? Surely a moderator has the ability to explain their actions, as an expert?

Comment: Stack Exchange is *not* a forum

Comment: @xtian, excuse me, you label me a troll? [Read this reply by a Community Manager](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum/92115#92115) before you start unnecessarily labelling people.

Comment: Sabre Tooth is *not* being a troll. Meta is not a forum. Meta occasionally involves discussion-based *questions and answers*, but it's still not a forum. That's why there are still accepted answers. And to be doubly clear, you didn't call meta a forum in your post, you called Cross Validated one.

Comment: @xtian, you are asking for users to recommend a tool. Simply put, there are *very few* sites that would accept a question like that. Cross Validated is not one of them, neither is Stack Overflow. It's off-topic. You seem to be holding the phrase "on-topic" to its strictest definition of "about statistics" which is not how Stack Exchange uses the word. Each site has specific criteria to what it considers to be on- or off-topic, and recommendation questions rarely ever make it into the scope.

Comment: @animuson, "recommend a tool". And I also offered my thinking, which asked if a SHA-1 hash could handle 20k names without collision. WOW! I'm getting so much more help writing my post right now--where were you before, when I was first writing it? haha.

Answer (score 8):

I can't help but notice two things.

1. The moderator commented on your meta post. He didn't suggest that what he was saying was an answer.
2. You don't appear to have requested clarification from him.

Beyond that, the post that you linked to is from July 2010. Times have changed, and requests for off-site resources are typically off topic on Stack Exchange sites. I'm not intimately familiar with Cross Validated's rules on such things--which is why questions like this are meant to be asked on the local site, but I realize why you've extended beyond that--but I suspect they've implemented similar measures. It's quite possible that that "Data anonymization software" question should, in fact, be closed and/or protected for historical significance.

But I have to admit, even as an outsider, this sounds more like a question about security than statistics.

The best real step you can take is to comment on the meta post you first posted and say, politely, something to the tune of:

> @whuber I understand, but I'm curious for future reference why my question is off-topic. I read [*link to the other post*] and was under the impression because of that, that this question would be considered acceptable. I want to make sure I understand the scope of this site so I can follow it later.

If you take the inquisitive approach, that mod will likely be more keen to work with you and get you an answer. Maybe he made a mistake, it's possible. Maybe he didn't. Take a neutral approach, state what you know and ask for his input.

---

And just as an aside, please note that Stack Exchange sites are *not* "forums." They're Q&A sites that adhere to different rules than a typical forum, and the scope is a whole lot tighter.

Comment: Matthew Haugen, 'data anonymization' happens data before analysis. Think about hospital records. Data in the chain of custody between doctor and analyst. I'm trying to come up with a DIY solution like tagging each 'patient record' with a unique code. When analysis is performed, no two different records collide (appear as one). But its not for hospital, but as supplementary analysis of student assignments in a MOOC. I say this not to start a discussion, but to point out I'm in the ballpark--even if most posts at Stats.SE are specifically about math-stuff, where else? Not overflow.

Comment: July 2010 post, wow. [How many questions on meta have asked, “Why can't I ask this question when that question is open”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124635/165773)

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that many questions on data collection and sometimes, sanitization are posted to [Open Data SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com). This doesn't free the OP from the duty of reading and abiding to the rules in the help center, and inter alia, on avoiding name calling.

Most definitely, the OP should get rid of the notion that StackExchange is a forum.

Comment: Here's the numbers: OpenData: 0, DataScience: 10, Stats: 28 questions tagged as data-cleaning. Where would you post? Strangely, none have a tag called 'conditioning'--a term I hear in MOOCs such as John Hopkins's [Getting and Cleaning Data](https://www.coursera.org/course/getdata). Maybe the issue is not just much the field has changed, but also how quickly it's growing. There seems to be a gap--I don't see a FAQ in Stat's Help saying, "Before you post, know there are 3+ sites on data analysis here at SE--choose wisely." Just one of those funky things pinned to the top in forums. :P