# Why is my question put on-hold since there are plenty similar ones?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, close-reasons, broken-windows

Do you know is there anything different between my question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206889/are-there-any-examples-of-using-the-state-design-pattern-in-net-framework) which is put on-hold:

> "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." – Soner Gönül, Patrick Hofman, Daniel Kelley, Hans Passant, greg-449

and a lot of other question that are very similar but up-voted and not closed

- [Examples of Design Patterns used in Open-Source .Net projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036658/examples-of-design-patterns-used-in-open-source-net-projects)
- [Design patterns used in the .NET framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064440/design-patterns-used-in-the-net-framework)
- [Examples of design pattern misuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373636/examples-of-design-pattern-misuse)
- [Good Source Of .Net Design Patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324824/good-source-of-net-design-patterns)
- [Asp.net design patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793010/asp-net-design-patterns)

and so on and so on...

Comment: Just because we haven't closed those *yet* doesn't mean they are on-topic today. They *may* have been on-topic once, which is why we haven't closed them immediately at the time.

Comment: They should pretty much all be closed as well.

Comment: Could please the down-voters explain their votes?

Comment: I've now voted to close all the posts you linked to, thanks for bringing these to our attention.

Comment: Note this question belongs on [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com). The voter probably voted because they think the question isn't useful (at least here).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Me too. If the meta effect kicks in, they probably all will very soon.

Comment: [How many questions on meta have asked, “Why can't I ask this question when that question is open”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124635/165773)

Comment: `Could please the down-voters explain their votes?` No, I don't want to

Answer (score 11):

All the questions you link were from 2011 or much earlier.

In those days, the site rules weren't that strict as they are now. Those questions are kept, but all future questions should apply to the rules. Old questions without values are possibly deleted.

It seems your question got put on hold for the right reasons. And those questions could (and should) be closed too.

Comment: This is a good reason and good explanation. Thanks :)