# unfairness in stack exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons, off-topic, broken-windows

**Before you continue reading, I will be suprised if you can give a reasonable answer to this question, that supports the moderators over at stack overflow**

ok I admit, I'm not an expert on stack exchange websites. Though I've noticed some unfairness in stack exchange

this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31486898/how-do-i-open-solutions-in-the-practice-room-of-topcoder?noredirect=1#comment50938272_31486898

[image: incase link doesnt work]

does not meet the standards of stack overflow(I wrote it) though, the same question was asked here:

[Finding solution in TopCoder Arena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26302102/finding-solution-in-topcoder-arena)

[image: incase link doesnt work]

**and when I last found that question, it had a zero for question votes, and no closed or off topic suggestion to it. the screenshot shows -1 because I referenced the question in my comment of my questions, and the other screenshot shows**

Why is this? My question(which was inspired by the question just above) got a -5 downvote, closed as off topic, and deleted, but the other question had no issues at all? Not even closed as off topic?

The reason why I'm annoyed is because I asked a similar question because I thought it would be accepted(as the other question was) but I had a completely different reaction from the community. What gives?

Comment: answering my question is a lot more admirable than cowardly downvoting... just saying

Comment: What are you asking here? The first question is sitting at -1; why would asking it again be *more* popular?

Comment: it wasnt -1 when I looked at it before, it was zero

Comment: So you showed it to the same people who disliked your question...

Comment: it seems to be -1 because I posted the question in the comments of my question and someone found it. I'm asking, why was the initial question left with a zero vote for so long, and my question after a few minutes annihilated

Comment: yes, the other question was posted 2012 from memory

Comment: downvoting is not cowardly

Comment: the 2 who downvoted, I challenge you to give me a plausible explanation for what has happened, please tell me how this was dealt with fairly. A rookie in stack exchange like me, use other questions as a way of figuring out what an acceptable question is, the least you can do is advocate equality and treat everyone equally. Please answer my question

Comment: yeah it is santiago, it shows you have no argument against me, and have emotional investment in question I have, its cowardly

Comment: I would appreciate an argument downvotes

Comment: @tristo the tooltip on the downvote button for questions says: _This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful_. Consider it the default justification for downvoting any question on main.

Comment: research- I have search this issue on this site, and there is no answer
- unclear/not useful - it is very clear, I even have screen shots, I have compared the two questions side by side effectively
- it is useful to rookies of stack exchange who use other questions to determine if their question is acceptable, it will also determine if any bias is within the site

Sorry, when I say argument, I mean specific reasons, not the tooltip reasons which are(obviously have to be)ambiguous

Comment: Shouldn't this be on MSO?

Comment: @tristo I never said that I downvoted, and people do not have to justify themselves to you (that may come as a surprise to you).

Comment: @santiago I never said you had to justify your downvote, I requested it, and said that not doing it is cowardly. Thanks for your snide remark, you have shown me this post has affected you :)

Comment: not 'affected', but rather 'amused' - read this kind of nonsense many times before - do you seriously think that members are going to say "oh no, a stranger on the web called me cowardly, I *must* bow down to his will"?  Name calling such as that is never going to help you.

Comment: No Santiago, no one thinks that, I know that humans are emotional and saying 'cowardly' might annoy them enough to give me a response so I can understand their view, even if its aggressive. Happens all the time on youtube. It can help when you get no response

Comment: For the record, I have not voted on this question, but do agree that your SO post was off topic and needed to be eliminated.

Comment: and im not attacking the person, not insulting but judging their action

Comment: I am a new person to this website, I didnt know it was off topic, thought meta was for discussing stack exchange of course I will post in stack overflow meta next time

Comment: Next to where your rep is shown, there is a button called 'help' - that is a pretty good start (in fact, the topics in there are very comprehensive). Guidance is given on first posts by new users - if people do not read them, then it is entirely their own fault.

Comment: its not intuitive to think the help was a tutorial for the site, help is usually for customer support(contacting authors of sites for help with bugs) I cannot accept that to be my responsibility, but thanks for the info

Comment: The information was and is there, the rules of what is acceptable and not are there - there is no unfairness, your question was voted to be off-topic and not a good fit for the site, thus closed and then correctly deleted.

Comment: Oh thought you were talking about this question, I realized after I my question was closed that it was not a fit. I interpreted the guidlines wrong and thought topcoder was apart of the programming domain. The reason why I asked this question was because due to the other question I posted being on stack overflow for so long(and accepted by so many people) I wanted to know why it was accepted and mine wasn't, whether it was because it followed the guidelines and i missed something, etc. I saw SO community kind of hypocritical that he got an answer and I didn't. that I'm banned and he isnt...

Comment: That other question is awful as well... note, deleted questions count towards question bans as well.

Answer (score 17):

> the 2 who downvoted, I challenge you to give me a plausible explanation for what has happened, please tell me how this was dealt with fairly. A rookie in stack exchange like me, use other questions as a way of figuring out what an acceptable question is, the least you can do is advocate equality and treat everyone equally. Please answer my question

Sometimes we miss stuff. We have a massive inflow of questions on Stack Overflow, and sometimes things slip through the cracks. We're not going to start treating people 'fairly' by forsaking our policies just because we missed something. That's not fair to the people asking good, on-topic questions.

The other question isn't a gem. It'll almost certainly be closed.

Also, we're not Topcoder support.

Comment: its not a gem, but there is a large difference between the way my question was treated, and the other question, though both were as bad as each other(which I didnt know because it had a zero last time I saw it) topcoder is related to programming so I thought it was acceptable. please tell me why there was such a difference in reaction to the community

Comment: Probably because things have changed since 2012. People could be more protective of the site than they were back then. Maybe the other question was asked at a time when moderation-minded users weren't watching. There are plenty of variables here. We're not perfect.

Comment: I'm not asking you to treat people fairly 'by forsaking our policies' you can delete the previous question without changing your policies. 

The previous question had a lot of views, I understand you are not perfect, but with the reaction I had, it seems very plausible to say that stack overflow is not close to perfect, we are not talking about a small difference here, the other question had a lot of view(and no one picked up on it) and even had an answer?? This is a massive difference. I'm not the only victim to this situation.

Comment: @tristo I'd recommend reading the guidelines before asking your next question. A random 0-score question isn't a policy. Yes, it's a massive difference. That's okay.

Comment: And if the community spontaneously wants to be more protective in 2015, why wouldn't you clean up on the 2012 questions too. This seems very unprofessional, arbitrary and inconsistent.

Comment: @tristo As of right now, we have 9,804,110 questions on Stack Overflow. That number can only be truly comprehended when you try to review every one of them when you make a policy change - it's simply far too much. If every one of us were gods, we could probably do it. That's not the case here.

Comment: Do you understand how strange it is to me, I know its hard reviewing questions, but the other question had 45 about views, how can all of those people not see(apart from one which I was because I showed him) how inappropriate the question is, and even participate in answering the question, on the other hand 12 people saw my question, and it got annihilated, I feel like I'm living on a different planet. If I was a hated celebrity I would have used that reason as a valid answer to why it happened. I would be satisfied with how this could be

Comment: That other question was also around approximately 220,000x longer than yours was. The views thing counts hits from Google. And you're trying to sidestep the point - you asked an unacceptable question, and we took action. Don't point to another question and whine, that won't get you anywhere.

Comment: ^ This. The fact that a question _wasn't_ closed doesn't mean a similar question is on-topic, or should be left open. But hey, once you have enough rep, you can start voting to reopen those questions you think have been closed unfairly.

Comment: I thought assuming a large amount of people accepting the answer as valid meant the question was valid, but unsatisfactorily explained, it seems like that doesn't hold true. 200 people can look at the question and accept it, but that could still mean its off topic...

Comment: There are even questions that get thousands of views and make it on the Hot Network Questions list before being closed as off topic. To reiterate the point, you cannot determine that a question is on topic based on how many views it has. (That goes for votes too, by the way. Lots of upvotes does not make a question on topic either.)

Comment: [How many questions on meta have asked, “Why can't I ask this question when that question is open”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124635/165773)

Answer (score 13):

Tristo, you are absolutely right: in order for moderation to be fair, it must also be consistent. You do not deserve to be treated differently than another person who did the same thing you did.

Unfortunately, the community that moderates Stack Overflow (and the other Stack Exchange sites) is made of humans. Humans sometimes make mistakes. [This post that you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26302102/finding-solution-in-topcoder-arena) should be closed for the same reasons that your post was closed. The fact that it wasn't was a mistake on our part. Fortunately, your meta post has drawn attention to the question, and it looks like the question is in the process of being closed as I write this answer.

However, I must question the necessity of creating a meta post titled "unfairness in stack exchange sites?" You had several tools you could have used to draw attention to the linked question, such as:

- flagging the question for moderation attention.
- creating a post about it on [Stack Overflow's own meta site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).
- bringing up the offending question [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/).

Instead, you chose to create a post blaming *Stack Exchange* (not Stack Overflow, but the entire network) and accusing *Stack Exchange* of being unfair. That is completely unnecessary: it was a simple mistake, and there is no need to assign blame to anyone. Mistakes happen all the time; it doesn't mean that our moderation policies are flawed or that we should be any less strict about questions on Stack Overflow. Next time, if you see a mistake, just flag it and move on.

And no, the closing of your original question was not a mistake. Just because we made a mistake about a different question doesn't mean we made a mistake about your question. Learn from it, ask better questions next time, and move on.

Comment: Thankyou for your consideration Christofian. Your dot points show features that I am unaware of. I did not do a university course of how to use stack exchange sites. I am not blaming, my reason for using stack exchange is because this issue is related to the format of stack exchange, I want to make that clear, I realized that the question I had asked was inappropriate NOW. Though due to heaps and heaps of people accepting the question I have highlighted, I thought that the question I was asking was acceptable, I see no reason why there was such a difference in response in the community...

Comment: As I said, the other question even had an answer with upvotes, I read the guidelines and the question seemed to fit because topcoder is a programming site, and I'm asking a question about it(so about programming) Now I realized I read the guidelines wrong(due to reading the other question) now I am banned from the site, cannot ask any more questions. I personally see this as a huge issue do to the massive difference in reaction

Comment: @tristo `"I personally see this as a huge issue"` my point is that it's not: someone made a mistake on a website. I don't know if English is your first language, but if it isn't, you should know that the word "unfair" is usually associated with blaming people. I'm sorry about the question ban, but usually that ban is triggered after someone asks several badly received questions on a site. I can't see your deleted posts, but I'm going to guess that you have a few. My advice is to follow the [advice given here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/160606) about the question ban.

Comment: 'unfair' is not about blaming people, its about raising a mistake, not a personal attack. 'Usually' is not defined as a synonym for always, as a moderator, being a smart ass and saying English isn't my first language is not what I would expect from you. I have been well mannered in this issue, I have not personally attacked anyone, that interpretation is incorrect, I am raising an issue. Please do the same for me

Comment: my point was simply, there was a mistake from the community and moderators, and that it had at least a small effect on my being banned, I see banning me entirely because I my actions as inappropriate. Next time I will flag the question because I am aware of the feature. I cannot see why people are so against this.

Comment: @tristo the mistake may have had "a small effect on my being banned", but it can't be the only reason.